# overriding the fopen function is not called at some cases?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ld-preload

I was trying to override all file related functions of a certain process, as a preloaded library,
I have this code that I compile as a preloaded library and then I just run the process and look at the stdout:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <dlfcn.h>
    FILE *(*original_fopen)(const char*, const char*) = NULL;

    FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode) {
        printf("In our own fopen, opening %s\n", path);
        fflush(stdout);

        if (!original_fopen) {
            original_fopen = (FILE * (*)(const char*, const char*))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen");
        }
        return (*original_fopen)(path, mode);

}
```

this can be compiled with `g++ -Wall -fPIC -shared -o hooks.so hooks.cpp -ldl`

and then just use any program that uses fifos with:

```
LD_PRELOAD=hooks.so ./prog
```

problem is, it seems that the program is for some reason using the function _IO_new_fopen from libio/iofopen.c, so: 1. is there a way to force it to use fopen? how did it initially come to use this function? or 2. can I override it? I tried same signature but it didn't work..

UPDATE:
from some places of the application that callback *is* called, so I am sure this is some includes and there must be a way to override it.. but how ?

Comment: [This blog](http://12000.org/my_notes/system_calls_in_linux/system_call_in_linux.htm) might explain what's going on.

Comment: so, if it's an alias, why isn't my overridden function called? worht mentioning I've also tried overriding open, open64 to find those calls but couldn't find it

Comment: seems I am intercepting correctly all the fwrite and fread as well.. just missing the opens..

Comment: For C (not sure if POSIX has further restrictions here), every standard function may be implemented as a macro function (there must be a real function regardless, though), in which case it must be `#undef`ed. Not sure about C++, though.

Comment: @mafso undef in a preloaded library?

Comment: In the header. Your `#include <stdio.h>` may define a macro like `#define fopen(f, m) ( __builtin_fopen((f), (m)) )`, for example.